# How to check that for some groups $H$ and $K$ and $G$, $H \cup K < G$ holds?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

How to check that for some groups $H$ and $K$ and (an abelian, but I guess that info is not that important for the problem) group $G$, that
$$H\cup K < G$$ (or that the union of $H$ and $K$ is a subgroup of group $G$). 
Is it enough to check if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ or there's another condition that has to be fulfilled? All mentioned groups work with the numbers inside $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, the union of two subgroups isn't necessarily a subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $H$ is not contained in $K$ and $K$ is not contained in $H$, $H\cup K$ is *never* a subgroup. Otherwise, choose an element $h\in H-K$ and $k\in K-H$. Then $hk\notin H$ because $k\notin H$, and $hk\notin K$ because $h\notin K$. Thus $H\cup K$ is not closed under the group operation.

Therefore the union is only a subgroup if $H\cup K=H$ or $H\cup K=K$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

$H\cup K$ is a subgroup if and only if $H\Delta K=\emptyset$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you mean the symmetric difference, this isn't true. The symmetric difference is empty if and only if $H=K$.